# How can I update value in VueJs from api request so that my buttons will be updated without pagereloading or click action or is there another way?

Tags: javascript, python, api, vue.js

i've tried to solve the problem with putting while(true) inside created so that it will always keep updated by frequently sending requests to flask. Is there another way to update my value?

Vue:

```
        let app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          session: null,
          showAcc: "",
        };
      },
    
  created() {
    this.fetchLog()
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchLog() {
      let response = await fetch("/logstat");
      if (response.status == 200) {
        let result = await response.json();
        this.session = result;
        if (this.session != null) {
          this.showAcc = "";
        } else {
          this.showAcc = "none";
          setTimeout(this.fetchLog, 500); // repeats the action if nothing comes
        }
      }
    },
    logIn() {
      this.$router.push("/login");
    },
    logOut: async function () {
      console.log("Logging out...");
        let response = await fetch("/logout");
        if (response.status == 200) { 
          this.session=null; 
          this.$router.push("/login");
        }
    },
```

.... And flask is just a basic session returning response:

```
    @app.route('/logstat', methods=["GET"])
def logstat():
    '''Checking if user is authorised/session, returning username if so'''
    username = session.get("userid", None)
    return json.dumps(username)

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    '''Ending session/logout from account'''
    session.pop("userid", None)
    return 'OK'
```

And in my index.html

```
<div v-if=(session) @click='logOut'>
                <p>Logged in as: {{session}} </p> <input type='submit' class='log_info_button pointer' name='submit'
                  value='LOG OUT' /> <i class='fa fa-sign-in' aria-hidden='true'></i>
              </div>
              <div v-else @click='logIn'> <input type='submit' class='log_info_button pointer' name='submit'
                  value='LOG INN' /> <i class='fa fa-sign-in' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
            </div>
```

What I'm looking for is a method so that my Login and Logout buttons will update dependently on 'session' status if there is sessionid then logout will appear. if null then login.
May be there is another value that can help me instead sessionid?

`this.showAcc` is for showing 'My account' link in nav bar. It's also dependent oon sessionid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to refresh this information to do it in the backend (or a proxy, for that matter) is definitely not the ideal way to go.

If you need to stop polling the backend once you got the session info, then this is what you can do instead:

```js
  ...
  data: {...},
  created() {
    fetchLog()
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchLog() {
      let response = await fetch("/logstat");
      if (response.status == 200) {
        let result = await response.json();
        this.session = result;
        if (this.session != null) {
          this.showAcc = "";
        } else {
          this.showAcc = "none";
          this.fetchLog(); // repeats the action if nothing comes
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This would eliminate the need for the timeout on flask.

P.S.: if you want, you can also put a small timeout for calling `this.fetchLog()`, like `setTimeout(this.fetchLog, 500)` for half a second. Ideally, though, you would also have to store this timeout id and with it do a `clearTimeout` on exit (on `unmount` or `destroy`).

Comment: The idea is not to refresh but keep value updated. I see that /logstat is beeing called only when I click or refresh the page. I want to keep it updated just by itself. But for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: In this case I can recommend the last approach, calling it again with a timeout. I also think of a websocket connection, but that's a bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped.  I've changed a bit in my methods as well.

Comment: Is it ok to use sleep(0.5) in flask for /logstat request instead of setTimeout or is it not that commonly used?

Comment: Regardless of whether this works or not (although it should), delaying your backend response instead of the frontend request is not the usual solution for such cases

Comment: For some reason it stops updating after one login-logout try. I've updated my code now. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: It shouldn't, at least if the Api call returns 200 regardless, as it should from your code.

Comment: I can login and logout and from the request side it looks fine. When I logout it sends "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 200 - one time and thats it. No more /logstat request.

Comment: So I ended up with adding this.fetchLog() inside logOut: async function () {
      console.log("Logging out...");
        let response = await fetch("/logout");
        if (response.status == 200) { 
          this.session=null; 
          this.$router.push("/login");
          this.fetchLog(); 
        }
    },

Answer (score 0):

normally this is caused by use of `this` keyword in the response/error callback refers to the function itself, and not to the Vue instance; You can resolve it by

1. Assign the value of `this` to another variable and use that variable within the callbacks

also try to check login status when instance has been mounted, unless your session expires pretty fast there would be no need to constantly check login status.

```
    mounted: function(){
      this.checkSession();
    },
    methods:{
      checkSession: async function(){
         let _this = this;
         let response = await fetch("/logstat");
         if (response.status == 200) {
          let result = await response.json();
          _this.session = result;
          _this.showAcc = this.session != null ? "" : "none";
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the use of _ for? Can you explain a bit more 'Normally this is caused by use of this keyword in the response/error callback refers to the function itself, and not to the Vue instance'?

Comment: I've tried and it still doesn't update my buttons. I have to refresh .

Answer (score 0):

Is very unusual that a website updates current login state without user interaction, anyway whenever I want my server to update my page I use a websocket.